# Why use "behaviors" instead of "behavior" in "...students should have good behaviors in daily school life"

Tags: word-choice, exam-questions

> Middle school students should have good ______**(behave)** in daily school life.

The answer to the question is ***behaviors***.

But why use ***behaviors*** not ***behavior***?

Comment: Who said it requires an s?

Comment: The answer to the questions.I'm a Chinese students so maybe the answer is quiet strange.

Comment: "behavior" is correct. The sentence itself is not natural. I'd guess the source material is low quality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Behaviours sounds very strange here. I would use behaviour instead.

Overall this sentence is weirdly structured. Behaviour is not something you usually "have". The sentence is better written as:

> Middle school students should behave (well) during daily school life.

Or if you wanted to use behaviour as a noun:

> Middle school students should show good behaviour during daily school life.

Other verbs are available instead of "show" such as "exhibit" or "exemplify".

Comment: Okey,thanks a lot.But I'm a middle school student in China,so maybe the sentence is strange.